# How to display images from mysql database without overlapping, FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a problem. I write codes of to display images from mysql database to FPDF but the images are displayed as overlapping (in same position)

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$que1=mysql_query("select * from TableName);
ob_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage(); 
while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($que1))
{
$profile=$rw['profile'];
$pdf->Image($profile,10,'',30);
}
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

How can I display my images in vertical form?

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) I can see that Image method take `[x, y]` coordinates. So just for every image calculate new position:

```
$currentY = 0;
while ($rw = mysql_fetch_array()) {
    $imageSize = $this->getSize($rw['profile']);

    $pdf->Image($profile, 10, $currentY, 30);

    $currentY += $imageSize['height'];
}
```

**OR** try setting `y` to null - `Image($profile, 10, null, 30)`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with line

```
$pdf->Image($profile,10,'',30);
```

The first attribute is "file", Second is the axis X position, 3rd is axis Y, fourth is width.

Refference: [Documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)

Please give different x,y values to prevent overlapping